# How can make four buttons with same weight when I use constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I use constraint layout in Android Studio 3.01, I hope to the four buttons have the same weight, I have set `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"` for the four buttons.

But the four  buttons have different weight, what wrong I made?

[image]

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolBar"
        style="@style/myToolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBackup"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRestore"
            android:text="Backup" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRestore"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnBackup"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMore"
            android:text="Restore" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMore"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnRestore"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnExit"
            android:text="More" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExit"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnMore"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:text="Exit" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To : Lalit Singh Fauzdar

**Your code works well when screen dimension is 4.65''**
[image]

**But not good when screen dimension is 4''**

[image]

Comment: I just removed the linear layout adding start and end margins. That can be the reason as weight and chainstyle may not working for your condition. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the containing `LinearLayout` a horizontal orientation, and then use `android:layout_weight` to give each of the 4 buttons the same layout weight:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolBar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="@style/myToolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBackup"
        style="@style/myTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Backup" />              <!-- one fourth of horizontal space -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRestore"
        style="@style/myTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Restore" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMore"
        style="@style/myTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="More" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        style="@style/myTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Exit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a `LinearLayout` in `ConstraintLayout`, Just do it without the `LinearLayout`, and you're also using `Constraints` in all the buttons when their parent is a `LinearLayout`.

Here's the needed answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBackup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRestore"
            android:text="Backup" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRestore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnBackup"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMore"
            android:text="Restore" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnRestore"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnExit"
            android:text="More" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnMore"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:text="Exit" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've removed the style attribute from the buttons to test it in my project. Just add them.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! would you please to see my modified question? Your code works well when screen dimension is 4.65'' , but not good when screen is 4''

Comment: And more, Tim Biegeleisen's code can works well both 4.65'' and 4'' screen